# Can't run UpdateDoc function when using Redux and FireBase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux

PersonalSlice.js

```
 export const updatePersonal = createAsyncThunk("personal/updatePersonal", async (id, {getState})=>{
    const personalDoc = doc(db, "Personal", id)
    await updateDoc(personalDoc, getState().personal.updatePersonal );
});
```

Main.js

```
 const updateName = useSelector((state) => state.personal.updatePersonal.name);

const handleUpdateNameChange = (e) => {
        dispatch(changeUpdatePersonalName(e.currentTarget.value))
    }

const handleUpdateSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(updatePersonal({updateName , updateSurname, updateBirthday, updateStartDate, updateDepartment, updatePhone, updateMail}))
    }



 <Form onSubmit={handleUpdateSubmit}>
                        <p className="text-center" style={{ color: "#39ace7" }}>İsim</p>
                        <Form.Control 
                        size = "sm"
                            type="text"
                            name="updatePersonal"
                            onChange={handleUpdateNameChange}
                            value={updateName}
                            required
                            autoFocus
                        />
```

I can't send the data I want to update in the form to FireBase. My fault is most likely in the parameters.

Comment: Were my recommendations below helpful for you,do let me know if you are looking for some other information.

Comment: Have you got a chance to try out the suggested configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting a new project and/or are not required to have your Firebase data loaded into redux, you might want to give reactfire a try before trying react-redux-firebase. In reference to the above function call ,if the profile object contains a key or a list of keys as parameters, you can populate those parameters with the matching value from another location on firebase.

Setting config like this:

```
  userProfile: 'users', // where profiles are stored in database
  profileParamsToPopulate: [
    'contacts:users'
  ]
}
```

Results in profile with populated contacts parameter:

```
  displayName: 'ABC',
  email: 'abc@xyz.com',
  contacts: [
    {
      email: 'efg@xyz.com',
      displayName: 'EFG'
    },
     {
      email: 'pqr@xyz.com',
      displayName: 'PQR
    }
  ]
}
```

Please check the link here to understand the [parameters call usage](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/docs/api/useFirestoreConnect.md#parameters) and related questions [Update Data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976460/cannot-update-data-in-firebase) and [Update function in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686026/update-not-a-function-firebase-firestore) for reference.Also check the helpful documentation for [configuration for redux-firebase](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/)